# Unified primary reference

Tags: msbuild, msbuildextensionpack, packagereference

I am facing issue getting my project to build on server. The same project build fine locally on my machine (VS 2017 15.8). Teamcity sever also has the same `msbuild` tool version installed. It doesn't have VS 2017.

Project build on server results in following error:

> "error CS0433: The type 'OracleCommand' exists in both
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' and 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,
>   Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'

So far I have been able to pin point the cause of the error to due to autounify not triggering/working at resolving package reference (I am using package reference for nuget packages) for project build.

I also confirmed that teamcity server doesn't contain `Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.`

Any idea on how shall I proceed towards resolving this issue. I know installing VS 2017 on TC server will likely resolve this, but that's not an option now. Any ideas people?

Comment: I managed to reproduce the issue locally by changing path to Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions folder by renaming it. Next step I am going to try is to install Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem on team-city server:
- Copied Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions folder from my local machine to MSBuild/Microsoft older
- Copied Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.targets file to MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.Targets\ImportAfter folder

Above steps resolved the build issue on TC server.